# Copying files across hard discs while keeping the original file date?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems

I copy a lot of files (entire folder hierarchies) from one hard disk to another, or from one SD card to another. The copied files all get the same date (the date when I copied). The original date of the file is lost. How can I prevent that?

I.e. how can I copy from one hard disc (or SD card) to another *while keeping the original file date*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some utilities I can't live without. TeraCopy Pro (http://codesector.com/teracopy) and Beyond Compare (http://www.scootersoftware.com/features.php).

They're among the first things I add to a new system along with Better File Series and few other "must haves". With TeraCopy, I turn on the Test after copy feature which will read the original, the copy and compare the CRCs. It's especially handy for things like copying to and from USB drives, to verify what you copied is what you got. Also, it preserves the file date.

Beyond Compare is just, well, beyond compare lol, when dealing with folder structures either on the same drive or between drives. It's extremely versatile for copying or moving folder structures around, and then verifying the files actually match. It will even do a byte-by-byte compare if you want it to. That can really help when you have two files with totally different file dates but it turns out they're actually identical.

If you need a way to fix file dates, or rename groups of files, check out the Better File Series (PublicSpace.net) which I use extensively for file management tasks. I use Better File Rename to do normal or multi-step renames on a group of files. It allows you to see the resulting file names before actually doing the rename. Very flexible with options like replace 'those' characters with 'these', delete 'n' characters from the end, add to the beginning and a host of others.

Better File Attributes is quick and easy for changing file dates.

I highly recommend all of them if you do a lot of work with files and folder structures and moving stuff around.

Answer (score 1):

[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) can do this, under `Configuration` > `Operation` > `Copy/Delete`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do with with Microsoft's [RichCopy](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/d/0/fd05def7-68a1-4f71-8546-25c359cc0842/HoffmanUtilitySpotlight2009_04.exe) Utility, it gives you fine grained control of file copy operations.

There is a description of the app [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx).